# Is there a best practice for mixing React.js components from libraries?

Tags: reactjs

I'm just getting into react.js, and it looks like there are plenty of components from open source projects in places like GitHub that you can inject into your projectṡ.

For example: [here](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery) is an react.js image gallery that you can put into a webpage.

**Question:** What is the best way to implement such libraries into your own projects?

More specifically: when implementing libraries like this into your own project, is it generally considered an OK idea to just pick a separate element on your web page, and have it render exclusively to that element (i.e., producing at least two separate root nodes: one for your custom code, and one for the library that you injected)?  Or is it considered a bad idea to start multiplying the number of react nodes you are rendering?

Answer (score 0):

My view on this would be to simply implement those components at the location where you want them. I think it would be bad for the readability that I'd have to go down another component to see what is actually used and what's actually going on. Given that, when you change it, you'll probably have to change the stuff around it anyway, and how often will you actually do this without simply being able to take out the component and swap another one in?

It does depend on how the component works. If you can simply include it like:

```
<ThirdPartyComponent prop1={this.props.data} prop2={this.props.data2}>Images</ThirdPartyComponent>
```

I would simply choose to embed. If you have to write a decent bit of this I'd swap over to a wrapper, but only because my markup would become less readable, not because it wraps the third party library so I could theoretically swap it out.